# How can insert a yasnippet snippet not from the current major mode?

Tags: yasnippet

Sometimes I am editing multiligual documents (like jinja templates) and I just want to insert a snippet from something that is not in the current major mode. Furthermore, some document types don't have major modes and I don't want to have to bother to go off and make one or set variables to satisfy yasnippet. Is there a way just to look through all of the snippets to find the one I want?

I am imagining something where you run a command with a little path for disambiguating snippet names:

```
M-x yas-insert-snippet-from-all jinja2/if
```